# Prove that $ x^n - y^n = (x-y) (x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y\,+ \,\,...\,\,+ y^{n-1})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Prove that $ x^n - y^n = (x-y). (x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y\,+ \,\,...\,\,+ y^{n-1})     $; $\,\,\,\,\,$$x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Geometric Series with first term $x^{n-1},$ common ratio $\frac yx,$, the number of terms $=n$

Comment: To see concretely what is going on, first look at say the case $n=5$. Multiply out $(x-y)(x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4)$, and observe the cancellations.

Comment: Have you tried considering $(x^n-y^n)/(x-y)$?. This should yield an induction start for $n=1$ or $n=2$, whichever you desire, and you can then proceed to the induction step, assuming the result holds for $(x^{n-1},y^{n-1})$ and use polynomial division on $(x^n-y^n)/(x-y)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should not use "$\ldots$" in strict formal reasoning, so you should first of all agree that the second parentheses expression can be written as 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} x^{n-k}y^{k-1}$$
(for some nitpickers: under the convention that $x^0=y^0=1$). Then note that
$$ x\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n} x^{n-k}y^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} x^{n+1-k}y^{k-1}=x^{n}+\sum_{k=2}^{n} x^{n+1-k}y^{k-1}=x^n+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x^{n-k}y^{k}$$
and
$$ y\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n} x^{n-k}y^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} x^{n-k}y^{k}= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} x^{n-k}y^{k}+y^n$$
hence the difference is indeed 
$$(x-y)\sum_{k=1}^{n} x^{n-k}y^{k-1} = x^n-y^n. $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

1. Use induction or directly prove that for each $n$, $a\in \Bbb R$,
   $$a^{n+1} - 1 = (a - 1)(1 + a + \cdots + a^n).$$
2. If $y=0$ the identity holds trivially. If no, valuate the above identity at $a = x / y$.

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier to prove the special case when $y=1$, that is, $x^n-1 = (x-1)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2} + \cdots + x + 1)$. Accomplishing this, can you see how to prove the general case as a corollary?