# Proving identity for polynomials: $x^n - a^n = (x-a)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} a + \ldots + a^{n-1})$

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation

I'm tryng to prove the polynomial identity
$$
x^n - a^n = (x-a)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} a + \ldots + a^{n-1}),
$$
an identity I've worked with before but never proved rigorously. By plugging in various values of $n$, it seems that this identity only works for $n \geq 3$. If $n-1$, then the first and last terms become $1$ and the terms in between may not make sense (for example, $x^{1-2}$ may not make sense if $x = 0$ and thus has no inverse.) So I believe I need to start at $n=3$. (If this is untrue, please let me know.) Induction seems like the most natural approach.

Here is my attempt.

> We induct on $n$. When $n=3$, the left-hand side becomes:
> $$
> x^3 - a^3. 
> $$
> The right-hand side becomes
> \begin{align*}
> (x-a)(x^2 + xa + a^2) &= (x-a)x^2 + (x-a)xa + (x-a)a^2 \\
> &= x^3 - ax^2 + x^2 a - a^2 x + xa^2 - a^3 \\
> &= x^3 - a^3,
> \end{align*}
> which checks out.
>
> Now suppose inductively that for some fixed $k \geq 3$, we have
> $$
> x^k - a^k = (x-a)(x^{k-1} + x^{k-2} a + \ldots + xa^{k-2} + a^{k-1}). 
> $$

I'm not sure how to proceed at this point. I believe it is a provable result that $(x-a)$ divides $x^k - a^k$ for every $k$, so I can write $x^k - a^k = (x-a) g(x)$ for some polynomial $g$ of degree less than or equal to $k-1$. At that point, I need to use the induction step in some way, but I don't know how to write $g$ in closed form.

So my questions are:

1. Am I correct that I need to require $n \geq 3$?
2. Is induction the correct approach to proving this? If so, can someone give me a hint on how to proceed in the inductive step?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $ x^n - y^n = (x-y) (x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y\,+ \,\,...\,\,+ y^{n-1})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630478/prove-that-xn-yn-x-y-xn-1xn-2y-yn-1) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5En-a%5En%3D(x-a)(x%5E%7Bn-1%7D%2Bx%5E%7Bn-2%7Da%2B%5Cldots%2Ba%5E%7Bn-1%7D)%24&p=1). FYI, the formula works for $n=1$ and $n=2$, just with only $1$ and $2$ terms, respectively (e.g., for $n=1$, then $x^{n-1}=a^{n-1}=1$, so there's just the one term). As for using induction, you can use that, with one way being ...

Comment: (cont.) with one way being to use $x^{k+1}-y^{k+1}=(x+y)(x^{k}-y^{k})-xy(x^{k-1}-y^{k-1})$ (i.e., prove it for $k=1$ and $k=2$ initially, then use strong induction). However, there are also other simpler, more direct means available instead.

Answer (score 1):

Write the RHS in the following form:
$$(x-a)(x^{k-1} + \color{red}{x^{k-2} a + \ldots + xa^{k-2} + a^{k-1}})=(x-a)(x^{k-1} +\color{red}{a(x^{k-2}+\cdots a^{k-2})}).$$

Can you take it from here using the induction hypothesis?